# Adding Security Headers to ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am in need to add some security headers to my new ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API. In MVC and webform I used to do with below codes in web.config file:

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000"/>
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff"/>
        <add name="X-Xss-Protection" value="1; mode=block"/>
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN"/>
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src https:; img-src * 'self' data: https:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' www.google.com platform.twitter.com cdn.syndication.twimg.com fonts.googleapis.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' www.google.com cse.google.com cdn.syndication.twimg.com platform.twitter.com platform.instagram.com www.instagram.com cdn1.developermedia.com cdn2.developermedia.com apis.google.com www.googletagservices.com adservice.google.com securepubads.g.doubleclick.net ajax.aspnetcdn.com ssl.google-analytics.com az416426.vo.msecnd.net/;"/>
        <add name="Referrer-Policy" value="no-referrer-when-downgrade"/>
        <add name="Feature-Policy" value="geolocation 'none';midi 'none';notifications 'none';push 'none';sync-xhr 'none';microphone 'none';camera 'none';magnetometer 'none';gyroscope 'none';speaker 'self';vibrate 'none';fullscreen 'self';payment 'none';"/>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        <remove name="X-AspNet-Version" />
        <remove name="Server" />
      </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

I know we can have a web.config file in .NET Core too but I want to achieve this by adding custom codes in startup class. I have found few articles using some NUGET packages but it would be awesome if someone can give me a clear picture to add security headers in .Net Core.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create a middleware class `CustomResponseHeaderMiddleware` like this in your code:

```
public class CustomResponseHeaderMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CustomResponseHeaderMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        //To add Headers AFTER everything you need to do this
        context.Response.OnStarting(state =>
        {
            var httpContext = (HttpContext)state;
            httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000");
            httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
            httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Xss-Protection", "1; mode=block");
            httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
            //... and so on
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }, context);

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

And register this middleware in `startup.cs` file

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // ....
    app.UseMiddleware(typeof(CustomResponseHeaderMiddleware));
    
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ankush. Looks perfect.

Comment: excuse me. what is the point of adding x-frame-options to an api? it doesnt make sense at all. same applies to CSP. no point. Those middleware will run for nothing.

Comment: I am working with the MVC and in my case the `OnStarting` is getting called twice. So, I am getting the error that the header is already there. Do you happen to know why may it be?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`NWebsec`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NWebsec/5.1.1) package to add security policy like this.

```cs
app.UseCsp(options =>
{
    options.BlockAllMixedContent()
    .ScriptSources(s => s.Self())
    .StyleSources(s => s.Self())
    .StyleSources(s => s.UnsafeInline())
    .FontSources(s => s.Self())
    .FormActions(s => s.Self())
    .FrameAncestors(s => s.Self())
    .ImageSources(s => s.Self());
});
app.UseXfo(option =>
{
    option.Deny();
});
app.UseXXssProtection(option =>
{
    option.EnabledWithBlockMode();
});
app.UseXContentTypeOptions();
app.UseReferrerPolicy(opts => opts.NoReferrer());
```

Remove server header

```cs
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.AddServerHeader = false;
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

or

```xml
<configuration> 
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true" />
    </security>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Adding `HSTS`

```cs
app.UseHsts(options =>
{
    options.MaxAge(days: 365).IncludeSubdomains().Preload();
});
```

Adding `Feature-Policy`

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Response.Headers.All(x => x.Key != "Feature-Policy"))
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Feature-Policy", new[] { "accelerometer 'none'; camera 'none'; geolocation 'self'; gyroscope 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; microphone 'none'; payment 'none'; usb 'none'" });

    await next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Farhad. Really appreciated.